# For a set of ordinals $A$, $\bigcup A$ is an ordinal

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

I need to proove that for a set of ordinals $A$, the set $\bigcup A=\{x: \exists y \in A, x\in y \}$ is an ordinal as well. I would like some help with proofing that $ \forall x,y\in\bigcup A, x\in y \vee y\in x\vee x=y$. Thanks.

Comment: What is your definition of "ordinal"?

Comment: An alternative approach might ask what the least ordinal $\alpha$ is which is not a subset of $\bigcup A$, show that that ordinal is a successor, and then prove that $\bigcup A = \alpha - 1$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm, an ordinal set $A$ is a set that sattasfies: $A$ is transitive, $\forall x \in A, x \notin x$, $\forall x,y,z \in A s.t. x \in y \in z, x \in z$, the term that I wrote: $\forall x, y \in A, x \in y \vee y \in x \vee x=y$ and, $\forall \phi \ne X \subseteq A$, there exists a minimal member according to the '$ \in$' relation.

Comment: @PatrickStevens I didn't quite understand you, could you explain it more specifically?

Comment: @Patrick: That's patently false, though.

Comment: @J.Doe: What do you already know about ordinals, though?

Comment: חג שמח, @AsafKaragila. I've managed to proove most of the conditions about the ordinality of $\bigcup A$ except of the last 2 conditions I've write.
I know some basic theorems about ordinals.

Comment: Yes, but what are the basic theorems? For example, do you know that an ordinal is a set of ordinals?

Comment: No, I did not know that. The 2 theorems I know about the ordinals in generally are that if A is an ordinal so $S(A)$ is an ordinal, and that if $a,b,$ are ordinals that satesfies $a\in b$ then $S(a) \in b \vee S(a)=b$. The rest of the theorams are about finite ordinals ($\in \omega$) and about the ordinal $\omega$.